# Whiteboard VS Real IDE Interview test

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages

What in your opinion is a better way to test an applicant - have them write pseudo code on the whiteboard, or write specific code on the computer using Visual Studio?

In both cases questions concern manipulating some data structures. I know by myself that whiteboard can be more nerve wracking but could be good to see how the person acts under pressure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the applicant and the position they are applying for. If it is entry level, I'd say pseudo code on the board, that way you can test their logical thinking and not get caught up on language/framework specifics.

If you are looking for someone who is seasoned in a specific language, I'd probably vote for coding in their IDE of choice for that language. I'd also of course ask language specific questions.

I'm not too sure why you'd be very interested in seeing how someone codes under pressure. There are always of course deadlines and critical issues that can cause pressure, but unless your environment is always under pressure I'd question why you are really interested in that aspect.

I'd probably even go out on a limb and ask the applicant their preference on white board vs. IDE and have the exercise available in both formats.

Comment: "their IDE of choice for that language" - in which case ask in advance, since you might not have their IDE of choice. As it happens, I think my preferred text editor is on the USB drive on my keyring, but that's something of a fluke.

Answer (score 0):

My take is this.

What are you more interested in testing them on. Their ability to remember syntax and specific classes or their ability to break down a concept and communicate at a high level their approach to the solution?

If you are more interested in the former then use the IDE.

If you are more interested in the latter use the Whiteboard.

Granted most IDE's will do the mundane syntax checking and help you with references etc. But on a whiteboard I wouldn't be looking at this at all. I would be looking strictly for conceptual understanding

Just my 2c